# How to describe collaboration?

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, idiom, science

I am looking for ways to describe collaboration in Latin.
My main interest is scientific collaboration, if the type matters.
I would like to have both a verb "to collaborate" and a noun "collaboration".
These English words have obviously a Latin origin, but I have been unable to find *collaborare* or *collaboratio* in Latin dictionaries, so I assume they are not found in classical literature.
Are there better words for this kind of thing?
I prefer attested classical expressions, but later ones are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For referring to a collaborator, have you thought of *socius* or *adiutor*? The latter does not necessarily imply a subordinate role and can quite well be used of equals in a partnership. Each has a wide range of application, but the sense is always of working together in the same enterprise.

To describe a collaboration on matters scientific, it's probably better to try working round the subject. This would allow you to use such words/phrases as *una experire* to imply the relationship between co-workers: e.g. *Gaius et Marcus una operabantur.*

None of this is in the way of objecting to *collaborare*, etc., which strike me as perfectly valid but not quite the thing for a scientific dissertation in proper classical style - if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I think *socius* is an excellent word. It might be good to work around *collaborare*, but having such a verb available just in case is useful.

Answer (score 4):

I have found *[collaboro](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?p=340)/collaborar*e in the Gaffiot (lit. *work in concert*) with reference to *cum, laboro* and Tertullian *On Repentance* :

> Non potest corpus de unius membri vexatione laetum agere: condoleat
>   universum et ad remedium **conlaboret** necesse est.
>
> [*De Paenitentia*](http://www.tertullian.org/latin/de_paenitentia.htm), Tertulliani

A [translation](http://www.tertullian.org/anf/anf03/anf03-47.htm#P11261_3190842) uses "join with one consent". The same dictionary [provided](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?p=341) *collega* (colleague) and *collegarius* (one of the colleagues), refering to *cum, lego* and noting *conlega sapientae* from Cicero's *De natura deorum* :

> Metrodori vero, qui est Epicuri **collega sapientiae**, multa inpudentiora
>   recitabat; accusat enim Timocratem, fratrem suum, Metrodorus, quod
>   dubitet omnia, quae ad beatam vitam pertineant, ventre metiri, neque
>   id semel dicit, sed saepius.
>
> [*De natura deorum*](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/De_natura_deorum/Liber_I), Cicero

A [translation](https://archive.org/stream/denaturadeorumac00ciceuoft#page/108/mode/2up) says *co-partner in philosophy*, which feels like some colleague...

Comment: I am now convinced that *collaborare* (or *conlaborare*) is good, but *collega* might not be what I'm looking for. My understanding is that it is closer to "colleague" than "collaborators". For example, all mathematicians are my colleagues, but only few of them my collaborators.

Comment: Finding a fitting word, good classical style but not prone to misunderstandings in modern use, is not easy. I'm hesitant with "associate" as well, since it is not clear (to me) if working together is involved. But if *collaborare* is fine, one should be able to derive *collaborator*, attested by itself or not. I'm not sure there is a better choice.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta It exists later [it seems](http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/LIBELLIFIUS), but _duCange_ is completely obscure to me. It is indeed not easy. The _association_ (adsocietas) may be too tight a partnership to describe what you mean...

Answer (score 3):

collaboro  or conlaboro is also in L/S, with the same unique reference to the early Christian author Tertullian (who writes fairly decent classicising Latin). It is a correctly formed prefixed verb and I would think it mere chance that it is not attested in classical authors.

http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcollaboro

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion may or may not fit the spirit of your question, but the [*Creator ineffabilis*](http://www.preces-latinae.org/thesaurus/Varia/CreatorIneff.html) (*Student's Prayer* of Thomas Aquinas) is beautifully written and includes a request that God collaborate with the three stages of a student's work:

> Ingressum instruas,
>   progressum dirigas,
>   egressum compleas.

These are all classically attested words (obviously), though they certainly are not stand-ins for the more prosaic "collaborate."

Comment: This is more in the spirit of a student-advisor collaboration than collaboration between peers. Not exactly what I looked for, but still useful.